# Why GUI disappears when running R script in batch mode?

Tags: r, user-interface, batch-file, gtk

I've written a GUI in R using `RGtk2` library.The name for this file is **myGui**. The following code is the batch file to run my R script using batch mode:

```
SET ROPTS=--no-save --no-environ --no-init-file --no-restore --no-Rconsole
R\R-3.2.3\bin\Rscript.exe %ROPTS% callingGui.R 1> myLog.log 2>&1
```

The code for **callingGui** is:

```
source('C:/.../myGui.R')

window <- myGui()

window$show()
```

The problem is that when I double click on my batch file, the window (as the output of my GUI) opens and disappears quickly! How can I solve this problem so that my GUI window wouldn't disappear?
Note that my operating system is Winodws 7.

Comment: Did you forget to call `gtk_main()`?

Comment: My main function is myGui.R which returns a RGtk2 window. This function is called. @andlabs

Comment: By the way, is `gtk_main()` a specific function?? @andlabs

Comment: Yes, it is a specific function; it is the function that runs the GTK+ main loop. I don't know what it's called in R, but your `myGui()` function probably has a call to `gtk_main_quit()` somewhere; this is the function that stops the event loop.

Comment: R in batch mode does not allow interactive code like a GUI. You'll have to open an interactive R session.

Comment: @Thomas so what should I do? You mean I should run my code directly from R?

Comment: @andlabs I don't know where to call `gtkMainQuit()`. I find this link helpful, however I don't know how to apply it to my code.|
https://books.google.com/books?id=hZvCvejIHHUC&pg=PA113&lpg=PA113&dq=gtk_main_quit()+in+rgtk2&source=bl&ots=VBuiZLSlqx&sig=TGXXmEkUqIjVJUskiwMHBTrhCz8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1g-Cw-IrLAhXFs3IKHWwjCmYQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=gtk_main_quit()%20in%20rgtk2&f=false